# unique record across multiple non-unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (tbl) of users that had multiple scans on the same dates, and some users had multiple scans on multiple dates.

```
user    date        scan
andy    20160301    T1
andy    20160301    T2
andy    20160301    T1
andy    20160401    T1
andy    20160401    T2
lee     20160401    T1
lee     20160401    T2
lee     20160701    T1
lee     20160701    T2
lee     20160801    T1
lee     20160801    T2
tom     20160501    T1
tom     20160501    T2
tom     20160501    T2
```

I would like the number of unique dates for each user (independent of how many scans occurred on each date), so something like this:

```
user    NumVisits
andy    2
lee     3
tom     1
```

I've tried several things, but the closest I have come is to this simple query:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(*) NumVisits FROM tbl GROUP BY user HAVING NumVisits > 1;
```

which yields:

```
user    NumVisits
andy    5
lee     6
tom     3
```

The problem with this output is that it accounts for the multiple scans on each date. Can anyone help me figure out how to get this output?

```
user    NumVisits
andy    2
lee     3
tom     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Count(distinct column)` for this:

```
SELECT
  user,
  COUNT(distinct date) NumVisits
FROM tbl GROUP BY user
```